# hibernate, spring - transaction

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have a project in Spring, where I have 2 connections to the database. Two because one is for read-only connections and the other is for read-write connections.

My problem is, when I try to invoke method to read only, I get:

`No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here`

Now I don't know, how to exactly configure my connections.

Below I've inserted my SERVICE CLASS file. The problem is when I'm trying to invoke method with `sessionFactoryr` , when I'm using `sessionFactory` - everything is OK.

My configuration is:

hibernate-context.xml:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans  xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
            xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xsi:schemaLocation="
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                ">

        <context:property-placeholder location="/WEB-INF/spring.properties" />

        <!-- Enable annotation style of managing transactions -->
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />   
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManagerr" />  

        <!-- Declare the Hibernate SessionFactory for retrieving Hibernate sessions -->
        <!-- See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html -->                           
        <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html -->
        <!-- See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/api/index.html?org/hibernate/Session.html -->

<!-- First Connection -->

        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
                     p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
                     p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
                     p:packagesToScan="com.esb.scs"/>

        <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
        <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
                    destroy-method="close"
                    p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
                    p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
                    p:user="${app.jdbc.username}"
                    p:password="${app.jdbc.password}"
                    p:acquireIncrement="5"
                    p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
                    p:maxPoolSize="100"
                    p:maxStatements="50"
                    p:minPoolSize="10" />

        <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
                    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactory" />

<!-- Second connection (read only)  -->                     

        <bean id="sessionFactoryr" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
                     p:dataSource-ref="dataSourcer"
                     p:configLocation="${hibernate.config}"
                     p:packagesToScan="com.esb.scs"/>

        <!-- Declare a datasource that has pooling capabilities-->   
        <bean id="dataSourcer" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
                    destroy-method="close"
                    p:driverClass="${app.jdbc.driverClassName}"
                    p:jdbcUrl="${app.jdbc.url}"
                    p:user="${appr.jdbc.username}"
                    p:password="${appr.jdbc.password}"
                    p:acquireIncrement="5"
                    p:idleConnectionTestPeriod="60"
                    p:maxPoolSize="100"
                    p:maxStatements="50"
                    p:minPoolSize="10" />

        <!-- Declare a transaction manager-->
        <bean id="transactionManagerr" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager" 
                    p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactoryr" />



    </beans>
```

Service Class:

```
    package com.esb.scs.service;


import static java.lang.System.out;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.esb.scs.domain.User;
import com.esb.scs.domain.UserReference;

@Service("userService")
@Transactional
public class UserService {

    protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("service");

//  @Resource(name="sessionFactoryr")
//  private SessionFactory sessionFactoryr;

    @Resource(name="sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Resource(name="sessionFactoryr")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactoryr;


    public void addUser(HttpServletRequest request){

        logger.info("test");

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        PasswordEncoder encoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
        String hashedPassword = encoder.encodePassword(request.getParameter("password"), null);

        String login = request.getParameter("login");
        String password = hashedPassword;
        //String role = request.getParameter("role");
        String role = "normal";
        String ip = request.getParameter("ip");
        int active = 1;

        String referenceAddress = request.getParameter("referer");
        String sex = request.getParameter("sex");
        int age = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("age"));
        String country = request.getParameter("country");
        String city = request.getParameter("city");
        String education = request.getParameter("education");
        String profession = request.getParameter("profession");
        String branch = request.getParameter("branch");


        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        User user = new User();

        UserReference userReference = new UserReference();

        Date dateCreate = new Date();

        user.setEmail(login);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setRole(role);
        user.setIp(ip);
        user.setDateCreate(dateCreate);
        user.setLastLoginDate(dateCreate);
        user.setActive(active);
        user.setToken("");

        userReference.setReferenceAddress(referenceAddress);
        userReference.setSex(sex);
        userReference.setAge(age);
        userReference.setCountry(country);
        userReference.setCity(city);
        userReference.setEducation(education);
        userReference.setProfession(profession);
        userReference.setBranch(branch);
        userReference.setSite(referenceAddress);
        userReference.setUser(user);



        userReference.setUser(user);
        user.getUserReferences().add(userReference);

        session.save(user);
        session.save(userReference);

        transaction.commit();

    }

    public List<User> getUser(String name, String password){

        Session session = sessionFactoryr.getCurrentSession();

        String sqlQuery = "FROM User WHERE email='"+name+"' AND password = '" +password+ "'" ;

        Query query = session.createQuery(sqlQuery).setMaxResults(1);

        return query.list();

    }


    public void updateUUID(String uuid, String login, String password){

        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        String hql = "update User set token = :token where email = :login and password = :password";

        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);

        query.setString("token", uuid);
        query.setString("login", login);
        query.setString("password", password);

        query.executeUpdate();

        transaction.commit();

    }





}
```

In addition, I have

```
<filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
      </filter>
      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
```

in my web.xml.

According to your advice, if I add `@Transactional("transactionManagerr")` to my methods - it doesn't change anything, I still get the error.

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to specify transaction manager name in `@Transactional` (e.g. `@Transactional("transactionManagerr")`) annotation. Read 
[Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-multiple-tx-mgrs-with-attransactional) and [Jira](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-3955)

Comment: Try to annotate each method instead of class level. What's your view layer? Why do you need this strange `OpenSessionInViewFilter` filter?

Comment: OK, i made it... thants for help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using transactional annotations you do not need to manually create a transaction in your service class.

You have specifed the class is transactional this means each method will have its own transaction created by spring.

You can also specifiy transactional on each method and further specifiy read only as and when required.

If you are using two different datasources you also need to specify which transaction manager is to be used.

```
<bean id="transactionManagerr" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager"                p:sessionFactory-ref="sessionFactoryr">
    <qualifier value="transactionManagerr"/>            
</bean>
```

And in yr service class you do this :

```
@Transactional(value = "transactionManagerr")
```

Also I would think about renaming everything, just appending "r" to everything is not really descriptive.

Comment: OK, i was trying with naming transitions and without - it doesn't work . Maybe there is some other problem - the web.xml configuration ? How should looks like the web.xml config? i have: `<filter>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter</filter-class>
      </filter>
      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>hibernateFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>`

Comment: You don't need to supply a filter mapping for hibernate its alls et up in app context. Yours looks correct, I have two transactinomanagers myself, but I specify which is used on each method usign annotations. With no manual creation of them.

Comment: But if i don't add Filter, `transactionManagerr` dosn't works nor `transactionManager`, if i add Filter then only `transactionManager` works - so i think, that i need Filter, cose without it nothing works

Comment: @Ilkar No. Filter mappings have nothing to do with back end db transactions.

Comment: ok, but if i delete FILTER i have `No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here`

Comment: @Ilkar Use annotation on each method, specify which transactionmanager to use, remov eyour manaually coded tranasctions  and change your app context to specify qualifier value (update dmy answer)

Comment: OK, i made it. Thank you. (hou have right - i don't need Filter)